# how i can use preg_match for check arabic and english and number and " - "letters?

Tags: php, preg-match, arabic

i want to check following by function preg_match:
1)Arabic letters
2)English letters
3)numbers
4)spaces, dashes ( - ) and single quotes ( ' )
i use php language 
 i tried

```
preg_match("~^[a-z\-'\s]{1,60}$~i", $nam)
```

Comment: Did you tried anything? Or you want someone to do-it-for-you? Please read [help].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this character class : `\p{Arabic}`

Example:

```
preg_match("~^[a-z\-'\s\p{Arabic}]{1,60}$~iu", $nam)
```

strings are treated as utf8 with the `\u` modifier

Comment: thanks very good its exactly